# Error while creating database table with auto increment

Tags: database, oracle, auto-increment

I want to make `auto increment` here with the table creation but it gives an error. The database is an `oracle` database. The `SQL` is shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE Continents 
    ( 
      ConId   INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
      Continent VARCHAR(25),
    );
```

Comment: Missing keyword

Comment: i am just want auto increment primary key by 1

Comment: 1) Extra comma after the last column. 2) extra comma between `starts with` and `increment by`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8ccd980901d7d9674dae6dbbb3a61f5a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this part

```
(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)
```

Use this syntax.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Continents 
    ( 
      ConId   INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
      Continent VARCHAR(25),
    );
```

The value of `ConId` will start at 1 (one) and always increment by one.

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=588df97cfd8afaddb2481f332e843d01)
Also refer to [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6)<sup>1</sup>

> The following statement creates a table t1 with an identity column id. The sequence generator will always assign increasing integer values to id, starting with 1.
> `CREATE TABLE t1 (id NUMBER GENERATED AS IDENTITY);`

<sup>1</sup>SQL Language Reference (Oracle 21c) - CREATE TABLE

Comment: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210200", line 673
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210200", line 659
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 18

4.       name_cont VARCHAR(25),
5.     );

Comment: show this issue

Comment: @MuhammadAdeel ORA-06512 is a PL/SQL error code so obviously the code in your question is not the code you are getting the error for since the code in your question is pure SQL and **not** PL/SQL.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeel It appears that you are using [Oracle Apex](https://apex.oracle.com/en/) which is not the same as Oracle database. Maybe you should add the "oracle-apex" tag to your question.

Comment: Sequence definition is possible inside the brackets after `autoincrement` keyword, but sequence definition doesn't use comma to separate options. See [`identity_clause`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__CJAECCFH). Original question has two typos